# Microsoft Access DDL for new bigint fields

Tags: ms-access

Access 2016 added support for "Large Number" fields, a 64-bit integral type. How can I use CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE DDL statements to create fields of this type?

Comment: Have you tried specifying _LongLong_ as the data type?

Comment: I have wondered about this myself. As far as I know, the Access ODBC driver has not been updated to accommodate the 64-bit integer column type. (There is an Access_2016 version of the Access Database Engine redistributable, but it appears to be the RTM version which, I believe, pre-dates the Access_2016 update that added the new type.)

Comment: “longlong” does not seem to work; i have also tried other guesses like “biginteger” without success.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [reference on data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sql-data-types) hasn't been updated since Access 2013, so I haven't got a clue how to do it through DDL. I do know how to do it using DAO, though.

Comment: There is a bit of info here that might help https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-the-large-number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70

Comment: @banana I see this question is both gathering close votes and downvotes. Perhaps it'd benefit from you having a generic attempt that fails + an error message to show you've put in some effort (e.g. `CREATE TABLE Table1(Column1 BIGINT)`), it's a good question imo

Comment: @Minty I've read that document, but it doesn't have any relevant information. It describes the implications of adding a bigint field to a table, but does not describe an ODBC or OLEDB datatype (or mention SQL at all).

Comment: Try linking to an existing table on SQL server. You see that the datatype becomes a DECMIAL type. This type is supported in both x32 and x64 bit versions of Access (in VBA you use a variant type to hold such values). So you do NOT need to use the x64 bit version of Access to get support for sql longs. Normally access works quite well without this new feature and sees such columns as a string. You can still get/set such values as a string, but now you can use/get an actual number type column. So the DDL data type will be a DECMIAL type.

Comment: Having said the above, I don't know if you can use DDL + DAO to create this data type. I know you can with ADO. This is "one" issue you have to check. I would double check what the actual data type Access uses with a linked table. The data type it shows is the type you have to create.

Comment: Actually, it displays as a "large number" data type. You have to turn this feature on - outlined here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/03/06/new-in-access-2016-large-number-bigint-support/

Comment: I have turned the feature on. There is no problem creating these columns using the Access UI. You don’t need to link to a SQL Server database, either; it’s native in Access as of the march 2017 update. What I want to know is whether it is possible to create such a column using DDL.

Comment: Create a new query in Access and then click the Parameter button to add a new parameter.  In the Parameters dialogue window, the right drop down ComboBox contains a list various data types.  Is the new "Large Number" field in the list?  If it is, then add a new parameter with some name (e.g. "MyParam").  Now inspect the SQL and it will reveal the SQL datatype that could likely also be used in DDL statements.  Sorry, but I don't have the newest version to test this myself.

Comment: hey, that's a good idea! by doing this i was able to discover that the list of DDL column types does *not* correspond directly to the list of field types, and isn't exhaustive: https://i.imgur.com/HiLQ6Mn.png

Comment: sadly, this means there is probably no way to do what i want. do you want to post that as an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as of January 2019. Using the Query Parameters dialog in a design screen, it's possible to get an exhaustive list of Access SQL types and and (by using sql view) their DDL equivalents:

[image: an image of the Query Parameters dialog, contrasted with the table design view]

There is no Access SQL data type available which corresponds to the field type Large Number.